# Failed setting up tomcat in intellij community through gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, tomcat

Failed setting up tomcat in intellij community through gradle

## so this is my build.gradle file I added bmuschko gradle tomcat plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.7.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final"

// If we are using mapstruct in test code
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '6.0.9'

    def tomcatVersion = '9.0.1'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:9.0.0.M6",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
}

tomcat {
    httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
    ajpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
    httpPort = 8080
    stopPort = 8081
    enableSSL = true
    contextPath = ""
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and after running TomcatRun --warning-mode fail --stacktrace :

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[-genkey, -alias, localhost, -dname, CN=localhost,OU=Test,O=Test,C=US, ...]]

Comment: Do you have some sort of dependency version mismatch?  Double check what Gradle is pulling with `./gradlew dependencies` and make sure they are what you expect.

Comment: @User51 where can I see those dependencies

Comment: Run:  `./gradlew dependencies` (or `./gradlew modlue:dependencies` if in a multi-module build).